# ng-click not working as expected

Tags: angularjs, scrollto, angularjs-ng-click

I am calling an `ng-click` `scrollTo` function and passing dynamic id to it, but the id is not rendered and the function gets called.

HTML:

```
<a data-ng-click="scrollTo('div{{+$index}}')" href="javascript:void(0)">Click</a>
```

Script:

```
$scope.scrollTo=function(divId){
 console.log(divId);
}
```

I get div{{+$index}} in console instead of div0

Answer (score 1):

Probably easier to clean this up and just pass the `$index` - then format the ID in the controller:

```
<a data-ng-click="scrollTo($index)" href="javascript:void(0)">Click</a>

$scope.scrollTo=function(index){
    var divId = "div" + index;
    console.log(divId); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this: `data-ng-click="scrollTo({{('div'+$index) | json }})"`

Comment: That didn't work and I get div{{+$index}} in console instead of div0

Comment: It doesn't make sense because I didn't added "{{" after the `'div' string. Try to copy & paste my expression